# How to show other columns in php session

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to extract other user info when I log in. I have managed to enable myself to login using my email address and password but I am struggling to show my first/last name etc.

I am logging in like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '". $email ."' AND user_password = '". $password ."'" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
    header('Location: dashboard.php');
} else {
    echo 'fail!';
}
```

Then in my header I have:

```
session_start();
if( !isset($_SESSION['user_email']) ){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
} else{
    $email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
    echo 'Logged in';
}
```

But fi I try to echo out user_firstname or user_lastname it fails of course I am just not sure where this gets set?

Comment: what about fetching a row?

Comment: You have to pass other details with user_email. OR even best, you can perform mysql query. using the user_email to get other detail from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use read a row from the query, then set session variables from that.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $row['user_firstname'];
    $_SESSION['user_lastname'] = $row['user_lastname'];
    header('Location: dashboard.php');
} else {
    echo 'fail!';
}
```

You can print the session variables in the header.

```
session_start();
if( !isset($_SESSION['user_email']) ){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
} else{
    $email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
    echo 'Hello, ' . $_SESSION['user_firstname'];
}
```

You could also just put the entire row into the session:

```
$_SESSION['user_data'] = $row;
```

Then you can use `$_SESSION['user_data']['user_firstname']` to get specific fields.

Comment: Good plus point explaining about sticking the `$row` data straight into a(nother) array (`$_SESSION`) `:-)`

Comment: Ok so that makes perfect sense, in the header when im setting the session what would be the best method of showing such info?

Comment: I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Right I see where I was going wrong! I appreciate the time for explaining to me.